# Implementation of a* algorithm on turtlebot simulation

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo. I am trying to implement relaxed a* algorithm as given in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4A_niNlDdg) tutorial. I am new to ROS and I dont have actual turtlebot. I want to run this with a simulation of turtlebot.

I am getting following error when I run `roslaunch relaxed_astar test.launch`:

```
process[move_base-27]: started with pid [14681]
[ INFO] [1521382205.529584483]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1521382205.668392247]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.3.0/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 737 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
[ INFO] [1521382206.283305266]: Zeroconf: service successfully established [turtlebot][_ros-master._tcp][11311]
[ INFO] [1521382208.668656600]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.3.0/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 737 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
[ WARN] [1521382211.190876509]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.100752 timeout was 0.1.
```

This is my `test.launch` file:

```
 <launch>
 <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/minimal.launch"></include>

   <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch">
     <arg name="rgb_processing" value="false" />
     <arg name="depth_registration" value="false" />
     <arg name="depth_processing" value="false" />
     <arg name="scan_topic" value="/scan" />
   </include>

   <!-- Map server -->
   <arg name="map_file" default="/home/deepali/catkin_ws_turtlebot/src/relaxed_astar/maps/my_map.yaml"/>
   <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

   <!-- Localization -->
   <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
   <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
   <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
   <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl/amcl.launch.xml">
     <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
     <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
     <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
   </include>

   <!-- Move base -->
   <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>

 </launch>
```

What changes shall I make in test.launch file so that I can test the algorithm with the simulation??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285761/implementation-of-a*-algorithm-on-turtlebot-simulation/) by [DeepaliA](https://answers.ros.org/users/34198/deepalia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JamesGiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/34047/jamesgiller/) on 2018-03-18**:
Do the launch files for turtlebot accept a `sim` argument?

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-19**:
You should probably look at using [turtlebot_simulator](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator) instead of turtlebot_bringup. Additionally, while you're still getting it working you should launch nodes one at a time instead of all at once (to help identify issues).

**Comment by [DeepaliA](https://answers.ros.org/users/34198/deepalia/) on 2018-03-19**:
Which launch file from above turtlebot_simulator package shall I use to replace $(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/minimal.launch and  $(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch   ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed my test.launch same as turtlebot_in_stage.launch which is in turtlebot_simulator package.
My test.launch file:

```
<launch>
      <include file="$(find turtlebot_stage)/launch/turtlebot_in_stage.launch"/>
</launch>
```

After that I have just added the following line

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="RAstar_planner/RAstarPlannerROS"/>
```

in move_base.launch.xml file.
It works fine.

---

Originally posted by [DeepaliA](https://answers.ros.org/users/34198/deepalia/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0